# Как правильно написать код в файле phtml, чтобы выводились категории от одной категории?

Tags: php, magento

Пытаюсь вывести под-категории, принадлежащие их одной категории.Имею код из файла left.phtml

```html
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
    <div class="block-content toggle-content open">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Меню') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                            <span class="count">(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

и благодаря помощи danil эту часть кода

```html
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда вставить эти строки или что заменить?

PS. Прошу не минусовать за повторный вопрос так как был задан незарегистрированным пользователем и теперь не могу повышать репутацию откликнувшимися.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите вывести подкатегории для строго определенной категории (её id можно узнать в админке) внутри шаблона left.phtml. Тогда попробуйте так:

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
$_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count();
?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
    <div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
        <div class="block-content toggle-content open">
            <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
                <dt><?php echo $this->__('Меню') ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ol>
                        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                            <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                                        <span class="count">(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ol>
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

ps. У меня не хватает баллов репутации, чтобы задавать вопросы, но если решение не поможет - укажите что конкретно надо сделать (с названиями категорий). А также расположение файла в котором вы вносите изменения (у меня есть подозрение что вы меняете base шаблон).

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!!! В шаблоне RWD в фале left.phtml, путь каталог/навигация. Не знал где написать эту часть кода.:-)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вывести все категории и их вложения для ID3? [Ссылка на вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/50710)

Comment: Danil, прошу вас помочь, последовательный вопрос. [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476820/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2-magento)